# How to get the position of listview with custom Adapter in Android?

Tags: android, image, listview, scroll, listadapter

I am developing an Application.

My Layout Screen is as below:

> [image]

In that I had Used **horizontal Listview** for Images.

My requirement is:

When I click on **Preview Button** the **image which are currently displaying on screen should pass to another Activity as a URL**. but how it can be possible I have really no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your image stored? in the resources folder in your device? On Internet? Why you need to pass it as a URL?

There are different ways. Sending intents with extras may do the trick. You can put the URL as a String or pass the location of the image also as String.

Anyway add more information about the layout and I could update my answer to give you more advices.