# How to get horizental Listview's position to variable in android?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, horizontallist

I am developing an Application.

My layout is **[in my Previous Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109638/how-to-get-the-position-of-listview-with-custom-adapter-in-android)**

For that I am using horizontal List view. In that I want to Get the position of the images while Scroll is changed.

I had tried for this:

```
hlv.setOnScrollStateChangedListener(new OnScrollStateChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(ScrollState scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for(int i=0;i<albumList.size();i++)
                {
                    if(hlv.callOnClick())
                    {
                        int id=i;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+id, 1000).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

But didnt successed. I didnt got the position of element in the Variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140623/android-onscrollstatechanged-scroll-state-idle-sometimes-doesnt-fire see this question once

Comment: What does your method `callOnClick()` do? Is it returning `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried the `setOnItemClickListener` for listview?. Even for a custom `HorizontalListView` it should be implemented as it is based on a normal `ListView`. Try it:

```
hlv.setOnItemClickListener(
     new OnItemClickListener()
     {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "POSITION: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
     }
  );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I got the position.

Comment: I need one more help. When user click on the button it should fatch the position which listview currently have

Comment: You mean display de position of the image on screen? I don't think if that is even possible. Anyway, you should ask the person who made the custom HorizintalListView. Accepting my answer would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sure I will. But Thanks Anyways. Cyaah